# Genexus 17 WorkWithPlus - Better moment to setup Multi Tenancy setting?

Tags: genexus

I need a recommendation.
I am starting a new project KB in Genexus 17 with WorkWithPlus. One of the requirements is that it must be "Multi Tenant", so before configuring Multi Tenant on WorkWithPlus, I prefered to ask...
When is the best moment to configure (WWP / Setting / Multi Tenant) to support Multi Tenants?

I think my options are:

1. At the beginging, after the first Transaction was created
2. At the end, once I finished all Transactions?
3. Any moment is ok?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8yA38kK9B0

Comment: I saw it. It does not recommend the best moment.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new system, where you have to create all the transactions from scratch, I would do it multi tenant from the beginning.